# How to get a similar hair effect

Tags: materials, particles, shaders, eevee-render-engine, hair

I'm trying to recreate this and no matter how much I mess with the particle system's settings(which include Brownian, shape & clumping), I can't get this soft fluffy effect.

[image]

Maybe I'm just using them wrong. Or maybe a specific material is required. Can someone help?

[image]

I restored most setting to default to start over and this is what I'm currently dealing with.

Comment: The number of hairs on that model is in the millions, if that helps :p

Comment: surely does not help my laptop.

Comment: I'm talking about the softness of the hair not how many

Comment: Is this for Eevee or Cycles? Maybe add a screenshot of your work. For fluffy fur, you need thin hair and a lot of it as Allen Simpson suggested.

Comment: Eevee, and I'm starting from scratch but i can send the model.

Comment: Try with new hair system, also, use the tools to comb the hair a bit and add more steps to make it look softer

Comment: can you add more details pls or maybe a screenshot

Comment: I think you need to tweak some parameters to make the hair length a bit randomized, to make them clump, etc, you should watch these tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQxkRSlJC54 ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVj1fETtuN8

Comment: thanks, I'll check them out

Comment: I just notice that you said you are using EEVEE, which means that it's going be very hard to get something closer to your image, take a look at this image which uses a material with Hair BSDF (cycles only) https://i.imgur.com/3KQqrfp.png

Comment: It's the only object in the scene right now so I can probably bully my laptop into switching to cycles  ; )

Comment: Can u help me with the settings for this result tho.

Comment: Can you use Blender 3.5? It comes with new GNs and assets for fur. There is also a tutorial video and a demo file with 4 different fur types (cattle, zebra, beaver, and sheep). Have a look here: https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-5/#hair

Comment: Yeah came out a couple of weeks ago. Thanks for the link